# Anuglar same criteria multiple checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have 3 arrays:

```
brands = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'SOME BRAND'}
    ....
]

sizes [
    {'id': 1, length: 12}
    ....
]

items [
    {id: 1, brand: 1, size: 1}
    ....
]
```

Brands and sizes become checkboxes. I need to set up filter for items by brands and sizes. I don't have a clue how. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

create your own filter https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

and in the callback do the desired stuff.